# Excel Automation Error Importing DB into Worksheets

Tags: sql-server, excel, adodb, vba

I have a workbook with 192 worksheets that correspond to the 192 tables in our mssql database. If I set up a given table in Data Connections Wizard, all of the data is properly dumped into the worksheet. However, when I run my code below, I get:

Run-Time Error '214767259 (80004005)' Automation Error Unspecified Error

About half of the tables populate just fine. I've noticed that I get the error once it reaches a field that has a large amount of data (rtf text). The fields that have that text aren't important to me, so if excel could leave those blank and continue on I would be happy. That large field is in a different column (sometimes multiple columns) depending on each table, so it'd be time consuming to have to go through all 192 tables to weed out an individual column to not import.

Why am I getting this error when I run it in vba, but the data connection wizard has no problems?

```
Sub GetData()

Dim cnDump As ADODB.Connection
Set cnDump = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=XXXX\XXXX;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=XXXX;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;"

'Now open the connection.
cnDump.Open strConn


' GET DATA
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl_name As String

Dim rsDump As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsDump = New ADODB.Recordset

For Each ws In Worksheets

tbl_name = ws.Name
ws.Rows.ClearContents

With rsDump

    .ActiveConnection = cnDump
    .Open "SELECT * FROM " & tbl_name

    For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
     ws.Cells(1, i) = .Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i


    ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsDump

End With


ws.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True


Next ws

cnDump.Close
Set rsDump = Nothing
Set cnDump = Nothing



End Sub
```

Comment: What's the Type of the "problem" fields? If you knew that, you could figure out how to exclude them from your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following procedure to import multidimensionnal recordsets into a spreadsheet, maybe try to have a look and adapt to your case ? This will allow you to deal with one field at a time and only skip the field that causes the error, either with a

```
Resume Next
```

Either by checking the contents of the field before copying it

```
If Len(Rs.Fields(a,b))<500 Then MySheet.MyCell.Value=Rs.Fields(a,b)
```

Here is the procedure :

```
j = -1

Dim MyArray As Variant
ReDim MyArray(RS.RecordCount, RS.Fields.Count)

If RS.RecordCount = 0 Then

    ReDim MyArray(0, 0)
    MyArray(0, 0) = "No Data"

Else

    Do While Not (RS.EOF)

    j = j + 1

        For i = 0 To RS.Fields.Count - 1

            MyArray(j, i) = Trim(RS.Fields(i))

        Next i

        RS.MoveNext

    Loop

End If
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If these fields that trigger the error do not matter to you, why not use the

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Method ?

Or if you want to avoid another error to be ignored when it shouldn't, maybe handle the error more precisely by adding :

```
Sub GetData()

On Error GoTo GetData_Error

[your code here]

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

GetData_Error:

If Err.Number=214767259 Then''assuming this is the correct code, you might need to track it     before using Debug.Print Err.Number

Err.Clear
Resume Next

End If

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Re your comment when you mention the Resume Next method will stop the whole copy for the given table, this is because you copy the whole recordset at once. If you looped through the fields the error would be for the field itself and then would resume to the next field instead of the next table. I should should have a sample of code that does that at work, will post tomorrow if you're interested.

Comment: The problem with Resume Next is that once an error is thrown no more data is dumped and it moves on to the next worksheet. If there was an alternative to ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs that moved cell by cell, that code would work.

Comment: My other though is maybe a different query which would exclude any column with an allowable length above 500 characters.

Comment: You could test the content of a given field before copying it, but again it don't see you doing this with CopyFromRecordset method. For me you defo have to loop through each field of the recordset

Comment: That sounds like it'd work - I'll continue searching this evening on how to loop through each field.

Comment: OK - will post tomorrow if you haven't found by then - don't have the samples handy